# Media upload on AWS with data - Lambda and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am making a simple app where the user can create a text post and optionally include media (pictures only for now, but videos in the future).

Currently, the user sends a `POST` request to API Gateway that invokes a Lambda function that inserts the post data into the database. This works great. API Gateway uses body mapping to format the event data.

In order to upload the media, it seems I have at least three options:

1. Make the HTTP `POST` request as normal *THEN* upload the media to S3 (via Cloudfront?).

   - S3 would trigger a Lambda function that updates the post record with the media url.
   - This would require at least 2 API invocations on the frontend. -.-
   - What if the media upload fails? I would have to invoke another Lambda function to delete the post. What if that fails? This is a rabbit hole.
2. Upload the media to S3 (via Cloudfront?) *THEN* make the HTTP `POST` request.

   - This would require 2 API invocations on the frontend. -.-
   - What if the `POST` request fails? I would have extra objects in my bucket. I suppose I could have a bucket cleaning scheduled task but ugg.
   - Would the S3 key not correspond to the `id` of the post? (`id` is generated on database insertion.)
3. Upload the media with the HTTP `POST` request in `multipart/form`.

   - This is how I have done it in the past, but I have also had a web server (not lambda). If the photo isn't huge, the transfer to S3 *should* be relatively quick and my lambda costs wont increase too drastically. But what if I decide to add video? Now my lambda invocations would be seconds long.

What is the best practice here? This seems like a common problem but all the guides I've found online are not concerned with the post data (only media data).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you involving the API Gateway? Why not just invoke your lambda using AWS's SDK? Anyway, I would choose option (1) i.e. create the post first since it sounds like the actual object your user wants to create. And if your media upload fails, you just trickle this error back to the UI and ask them to upload it again. Why delete the post?

Comment: Good question. I suppose separation of concerns. Frontend is totally naive of backend reworking its functions. Now that I think of it this may get muddled with versioning. Its funny you chose that one, because I thought (2) would be the best. Media seems to be of equal importance. In (1) users fetching newly created posts could get posts without their media.

Comment: I see, so your objects are made of two equally important parts (the text and the media) and you'd like to transport them in a single operation to avoid consistency issues. If you can restrict your text to less than 1024 Unicode characters, put the text into the key of the s3 object containing your media. You will want to reserve some characters at the front of the key, i.e. before the user's text begins, because S3's ListObjects API has a useful "Prefix" parameter, and you can make your prefixes conducive to searching. Then attach a lambda listener to create the DB entry *after* upload.

Comment: If your posts are more than 1000-odd characters then yes you need two operations and a cleanup process to catch the ones which failed. S3's object expiration should help clean up the media part which you will upload first (your option #2), you will of course move the media out of the auto-expiring bucket on successful submission of the text portion on your post

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks I'll post it as an actual answer in a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments)

Your objects are made of two equally important parts (the text and the media) and you'd like to transport them in a single operation to avoid consistency issues.

If you can restrict your text to less than 1024 Unicode characters: put the text into the key of the s3 object containing your media. You will want to reserve some characters at the front of the key, i.e. before the user's text begins, because S3's ListObjects API has a useful "Prefix" parameter, and you can make your prefixes conducive to searching. Then attach a lambda listener to create the DB entry after upload.

If your posts are more than 1000-odd characters: then yes you need two operations and a cleanup process to catch the ones which failed. S3's object expiration should help clean up the media part which you will upload first (your option #2), you will of course move the media out of the auto-expiring bucket on successful submission of the text portion on your post.

Glad to be of help